# Is there any Android email client that fully supports offline reading?

Tags: email, images, html

I'm using K-9 mail on my Nexus 10 tablet. It is a good client, but it does not fetch images in HTML messages for offline reading. It has a setting for fetch images, which I have set, but I'm not really sure what it does. Images in HTML messages are still not fetched. At the moment the message is displayed the images are loaded. If there is no Internet connection at that time, there are no images.

Is there any Android email client that can be configured to fetch images when fetching the messages?